# What is difference between search using `/` and `?` in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim I find search using `/` and `?` giving the same search result. So what are the differences in search using `/` and `?`

For example,

`/and`

`?and`

Both takes to next occurrence of `and` and `n` / `N` to repeat search in forward / backward direction works for both.

Comment: One difference I could find is that in `/` default search direction is right and down while for `?` default search direction is left and up

Comment: Does the behaviour persist when you don't load your .virmc (i.e. launch vim like `vim -u NONE`)? If not, then you must have a setting or plugin that is affecting the default behavior described by @Payel Senapati.